# How do I template nav bar across multimple websites using a class?

Tags: javascript, class, templates

Please check the code below to see why the nav bar won't show up on the index file even after linking it through a class. Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is my templates.js

```
class MyMenu extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML * `

<header>     
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="logo">Damian Roiz</li>
            <li class="items"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>    
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.btn').click(function(){
              $('.items').toggleClass('show');
              $('ul li').toggleClass('hide');
            });
        });
    </script>
</header> 
        `
    }
}

customElements.define('my-menu', MyMenu)
```

Here is my index.html

```
<head>

<script type='text/javascript' src=js/templates.js></script>
    
</head>

<body>

<my-menu></my-menu>

</body>
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, your code is broken: `this.innerHTML *`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am not very familiar with the class syntax so I really appreciate your quick reply!